# How can I set up my maven setting.xml through my code(pom.xml) or command prompt

Tags: java, git, maven, jfrog-cli

Actually, I'm executing my maven code on a different remote machine. My Java code depends upon some of the customs dependencies which are downloading from jFrog artifactory.
I can't set up my user-name and password on every machine. Is there any way we can do it through code i.e pom.xml or cmd.
Ex:setting.xml

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server><id>central</id><username>USER_NAME</username><password>$USER_PWD</password></server>
        <server><id>snapshot</id><username>USER_NAME</username><password>$USER_PWD</password></server>
    </servers>    
</settings>
```

Comment: Please explain more detailed what underlying problem you have, and how you are solving it?  Any reason you don't prepackage the final deployment for a given server and copy the tarball/zipfile out?

Comment: Do you mean using a common settings xml file for all the builds on various machines?

Comment: Please describe the underlying problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: FYI I was executing the code through the GOCD agent. I have decide to but _setting.xml_ in **Git**. Then GOCD download the code on any machine and execute by using '$ mvn -s settings.xml clean install'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you problem is about sharing your `settings.xml` across your different machine (like bamboo agent, etc), you may as well use:

```
mvn -s /path/to/settings.xml
```

The location of the `settings.xml` differs from your context; for example, if you put the `settings.xml` alongside the `pom.xml`, this would be:

```
mvn -s settings.xml clean install
```

I'd advise not to put this `settings.xml` in the same repository than the `pom.xml`, because you would otherwise put password in a GIT repository which you probably don't want.

And if you only want to share this settings with your personal computer**s**, you could probably use GIT as well: create a repository directly in the `~/.m2` with the advert effect that you should not touch the path to the `localRepository` (path is OS dependent).

The repository should contains a `.gitignore` with this minimal line:

```
repository
```

This is only to NOT store in the repository the cached dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you did is similar to my setup.  Once you added the server credentials in the `settings.xml`, you just need to add the repository as a profile that is always activated/running.  Like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
              <id>central</id>
              <name>libs-release</name>
              <url>http://artifactory-url/libs-release</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>snapshot</id>
                <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                <url>http://artifactory-url/libs-snapshot</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

All I did was copy paste this settings.xml across different machines.  As long as the network is reachable (I use vpn), then I can connect to the artifactory just fine.

Please comment if this is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)